# CAB installation failing on new Windows Mobile 6.5 devices

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile, cab, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-5.0

We use a CAB file through a webpage to deploy our mobile application to our customers. Now with the new Windows Mobile 6.5 devices, the cab file is downloaded as a .tsk file (when using the new Internet Explorer). Naturally the installation fails to install the application as a theme.

If the file is downloaded in Opera, or you change the file extension back to cab. The installation process completes. But the application can launch due to Missing Method Exceptions.

Has anyone experienced this? Does anyone know if there is a workaround for it?

We are currently builing the CAB using a vdproj in visual studio and signing it using CabWiz. Were using the Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with a specific version of the HTC Touch 2 ROM.

Apparentlly this is fixed with an upgrade of the mobile.

see reference:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=574121